# How to send a command through ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, geospatial

I have been working with C# ServiceStack.Redis (v3.9) for sometime, and I like to progress into GEOSPATIAL functionality.

I can send arbitrary commands using the following. However I wasn't able to find anything that would retrieve arbitrary commands from ServiceStack.Redis.

```
var str = "GEOADD Sicily 13.361389 38.115556 \"Palermo\"";
RedisClient reds = new RedisClient(host, 6379);
reds.WriteToSendBuffer(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
```

How can I retrieve data using the following `GEORADIUS` arbitrary command?

```
redis> GEORADIUS Sicily 15 37 200 km WITHCOORD
```

Unfortunately I cannot immediately upgrade the ServiceStack due to company policy. Thanks in advance..